# Using Listings Package: the Colour of the Text After the Listing is the same as that of the Identifiers Inside the Listing

Tags: listings, color, text

So I have some LaTeX which looks like

```
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times, hyperref, amsmath, listings, xcolor, enumitem}

\lstset{language = C++}

\lstdefinestyle{customcpp}{
  backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.09, 0.09, 0.09},
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=C++,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.36, 0.55, 0.84},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color[rgb]{0.34, 0.65, 0.29},
  identifierstyle=\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9},
  stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0, 0.5, 0},
  literate=*{\{}{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}{\{}}}{1}
 {\}}{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}{\}}}}{1},
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customcpp}
```

And later on:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
struct Transform
{
    sf::Vector2f position;
    float rotation;
};
\end{lstlisting}
```

The result of this is that before the listing, the normal text looks fine, the listing itself looks great, but AFTER the listing, the normal text retains the colour of the identifiers within the listing, so basically you can't see the text (off-white text on a white page).

Help plz.  This isn't urgent, but I would like to get this annoyance out of the way sooner, rather than later.

Comment: Try with `literate=*{\{}{{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}}}}1{\}}{{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}}}}1,`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!  Those braces, though.

Comment: @PeterGrill Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using an extra brace group around the `literate*`

```
literate=*{\{}{{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}{\{}}}{1}{\}}{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}{\}}}}{1}
```

seems to resolve the problem:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times, hyperref, amsmath, listings, xcolor, enumitem}

\lstset{language = C++}

\lstdefinestyle{customcpp}{
  backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.09, 0.09, 0.09},
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=C++,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.36, 0.55, 0.84},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color[rgb]{0.34, 0.65, 0.29},
  identifierstyle=\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9},
  stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0, 0.5, 0},
 %literate=*{\{}{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}{\{}}}{1}{\}}{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}{\}}}}{1},
  literate=*{\{}{{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}}}}1{\}}{{{\color[rgb]{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}}}}1,
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customcpp}

\begin{document}

Some text before

\begin{lstlisting}
struct Transform
{
    sf::Vector2f position;
    float rotation;
};
\end{lstlisting}

Some text after.
\end{document}
```